# Product list frozen on third page

Tags: magento-1.7, product, product-list

I have a shop and the client is now introducing the products. After having done so he told me that he can't navigate to page 3 of a certain category. I checked and it's true, the browser is just stuck loading forever that page, I don't even see any html changes or petitions in firebug. I assume this must be due to a corrupted product but I don't know where to look!

I am currently in the process of making a database repair on a development envirment but I'm doing this blind since I don't know what I am repairing and I want to know what happened.

Any help or advice?

Repair tool said:

> ```
> Add missing index(es) "FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID" to table "core_url_rewrite"
> Add missing foreign key(s) "FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID" to table "core_url_rewrite"
> ```

var/log folder shows only warnings that were there before. Server log says nothing

Comment: check the `var/log` folder for errors, or try adding breakpoints (or manual `echo "HERE";die()` or `Mage::log()`) in different sections of the code to identify what is causing the problem before repairing the DB. Maybe it doesn't need repair.

Comment: I can't debug since no html is loaded on that page, it just freezes the browser (well not freezes, it keeps spinning but nothing is loaded, no petitions, no activity on the network tab, nada)

Comment: You can debug starting from `index.php` (worst case scenario). Or you can start from the category controller in the view action. There is a long way to go before reaching the phtml files.

Comment: Do you think that repair log might have something to do with the problem?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what might be the problem. I'm "more blind" that you are on this.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found what was wrong. I cleaned up a bit my list.phtml file from commented code and did a reindex and it seemed to do the trick both in development and production sites. I'm puzzled.